# Passing files randomly to a program

Tags: bash

I have a program which takes files it reads followed by an output file as argument, explicitly:

```
./my_program file_to_read1 file_to_read2 file_to_read3 [...] file_to_output
```

and I'd like to pick these files to read to be N random files in a given folder. I would know how to list them, using something like:

```
ls My_FOLDER/* | sort -R | head -N
```

but I don't know enough about pipes or script languages to get what I want, especially adding the last output file seems intricate to me.

Is there a systematic way of doing that? (So far, I've used the previous line to move the files in a temporary folder before reading them, but it's taking much more time that the next steps, so cutting that would be a significant improvement.)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For N=100, this should do it (replace it accordingly to your desired value):

```
./my_program `ls My_FOLDER/ | sort -R | head -n 100` file_to_output
```

you can check the arguments that will be passed to my_program if you run

```
echo `ls My_FOLDER/ | sort -R | head -n 100` file_to_output
```

NaN

Comment: won't the `-R` output be different each time?

Answer (score 2):

Think you might be looking for [shuf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/shuf):

```
ls My_FOLDER/* | shuf
```

Comment: Beats my hack with arrays and $RANDOM and tells me about the existence of shuf

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to pass all files in the directory to your program and do the random picking there.

The ugly way is to do this in bash:

a. read the list of files into an array

b. generate N random numbers in a for loop using the built in function $RANDOM and index the array

c. execute your program with the string built up plus the output file

And you are mostly done except (1) the random numbers aren't uniformly distributed (2) there are going to be duplicates in the sequence (3) if your files have spaces you really need to read the bash manual on quoting, (4) I left echo commands in the script for you to see whats going on (5) I think eval isn't the safest thing to go.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

N=5

i=0
while read line
do
    array[ $i ]="$line"        
    (( i++ ))
done < <(ls)

echo ${array[@]}
echo ${#array[@]}

echo "---"
for i in `seq 0 $((N - 1))`
do
    echo ${array[i]}
    j=$((RANDOM % N))
    echo "j is $j"
    echo "arr[$j] is ${array[$j]}"
    ss="$ss ${array[$j]}"
done

echo "ss is $ss"
# eval ./my_program $args OUTPUTFILE
```